# how do I set a ring tone for a specific contact?

Tags: contacts, ringtone

I've searched for this here and don't see it. I've set a custom, contact-specific ring tone before but don't recall how. It doesn't seem to be under the contact, which is where it *should* be.

Phone is a 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found it:

```
Go to the Contact.     
Do not press Edit.     
Hit Menu.     
Hit Options.     
Select Ringtone.     
Set Ringtone.
```

Seems wacky that you don't edit the contact to change the ringtone.